# Convert specific value in numpy array to NAN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, na

I have a two-dimensional numpy-array. It has a shape of `(6994, 6994)`. There are many values of `-1000` which I would like to encode as `NAN`. I tried:

`array[array == -1000] = np.NAN`, but this gives me the error `cannot convert float NaN to integer`

When I tried to write a function:

```
def valtona(array, val):
    for i in array:
        for j in array:
            if array[i,j] == -1000:
                array[i,j] = np.NAN
```

I get:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I know there are some questions out there regarding the same issue, but I still didn't manage to fix it.

Comment: Try with `for i in range(6994): for j in range(6994):`.

Comment: `np.nan` is a float.  Your array is integer. For the `sklearn` use which is more useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use

```
array[array == -1000] = np.NAN
```

You just need to convert it to `float` first.

```
array=array.astype('float')
array[array == -1000] = np.NAN
```

Comment: Enjoy the comparison issues where float `1000.000000000001` != int `1000`.

Comment: Fair point, however the conversion will be to `float64`, not `float32`, with significantly better precision.

Comment: perfect, helped a lot!!

Comment: The `mask` could be calculated with the original `int` dtype array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.isclose() and set parameters to meet your needs to overcome the precision challenge of working with floats.

```
>>> a
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
>>> a[3]
4.0000000000001004
>>> a[4]
4.0
>>> np.isclose(a,[4.0], .00000001, .00000001)
array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.isclose(a,[4.0])
array([False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[np.isclose(a,[4.0], .00000001, .00000001)]=np.nan
>>> a
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,  nan,  nan,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.])
```